# Java EE 6 application with JPA 2 + EJB 3 cannot insert or update records on WAS - no errors

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, websphere, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I see similar questions asked not only on Stackoverflow and other sites, but there is no answer as a true solution for this case:

Nobody's using IBM WAS to deploy applications featuring JPA 2 + JSF 2 + EJB 3 ?

The best I managed to do was to get my application of such spec to select records from the database and display them on a dataTable, but can't insert or update any records - no errors or exceptions either - nothing in System.out / System.Err logs. The code runs just fine when deployed to Glassfish 3 or JBoss AS 7!

WAS 8.5 / DB 2 Express / Oracle 10g XE /

I'm using Apache MyFaces 2.0, tried switching to/from Hibernate JPA 2 (Hibernate 4) / EclipseLink 2.1 (defined them as shared libraries, eradicated any javax.persistence.* jars to avoid conflicts with what's already on WAS, and adjusted my persistence.xml every time I changed something:

My persistence.xml tuned for EclipseLink

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="fcodmkamp-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/fcodmoradata</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="fcodmkamp-createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="fcodmkamp--dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebSphere_8"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle10"/> 
         <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/> 
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
     </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'll be very happy if I hear that someone can actually develop and successfully deploy non-openJPA applications on WAS 8.0 or later especially Hibernate 4 or EclipseLink 2.1 and will be grateful if any know-how on how to accomplish this can be shared.

Comment: You are using a *jta-data-source*. Have you tried *transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"* together with a *non-jta-data-source*? Where is your EJB component (sesion bean etc.) or is it just JPA? Can you insert data from a plain JSP, just to make sure that your problem is not related with JSF?

Comment: Hi, no, I need to get this working with JTA. I can get my application work with EclipseLink, but no luck with Hibernate as all documentation from IBM and the sources on the Internet seem outdated for the coupling of Hibernate version 4 and WAS 8.x.

Comment: JTA means XA (distributed transactions). Non-JTA means "only" JDBC transactions. So what other systems are involved in your XA transactions (XA JMS, another XA data source, ...). If there are no other ones, please try the non-jta-data-source.